# Optimized MariaDB configuration on my Server to prevent lock wait timeouts

Tags: mariadb, configuration

I'm having issues recently with my galera cluster getting desync after multiple lock wait timeouts, is there any way I can improve my galera cluster configuration to prevent more lock wait timeouts from happening?

Here's each of my galera nodes run on 4-cores CPU and 64GB of memory, and I feel like I'm not utilizing those resources properly.

Here's my current MariaDB `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-data
socket=/var/lib/mysql-data/mysql.sock

proxy-protocol-networks=10.10.10.10, 10.10.10.20, 10.10.10.30

innodb_lock_wait_timeout=60
innodb_io_capacity=2000
innodb_buffer_pool_size=52G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=52
innodb_log_buffer_size=256M
innodb_log_file_size=1G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT_NO_FSYNC
innodb_rollback_on_timeout=1

innodb_read_io_threads=8
innodb_write_io_threads=4
innodb_purge_threads=1

thread_handling = pool-of-threads
thread_stack = 192K
thread_cache_size = 4
thread_pool_size = 8
thread_pool_oversubscribe = 3

performance_schema = ON
event_scheduler = ON

max_allowed_packet=256M
max_connections=3000
```

We have at least 20 apps using the cluster and I think my current configuration is not cutting out for it. Any tips on what variables to increase?

Comment: How far apart (ping time) are the nodes?  Let's see a query involved in the timeout.  (These, and possible other, questions will help us figure out what direction to look.)

Comment: Hi @RickJames, I pinged the other nodes from the first node and got these results rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.148/0.230/0.548/0.099 ms, rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.162/0.321/0.703/0.155 ms. The last query was an from event scheduler [mall_traffic.populate_traffic_data] Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Comment: OK, it is not network latency.  Now we need to see what is inside the transaction.  `lock_wait_timeout` has an excessively high default if 50 seconds; I do not recommend raising it -- instead work on speeding up the transaction.

Comment: I'm having suspicions that it was related to the events occurring on each node together, I have disabled the events on the 2/3 of the nodes and let a single node handle the events instead. I'm still monitoring the performance if it occurs again. Though I'm not sure if there are limitations regarding events when using the galera cluster.